# How to compare the first letters of a single sentence in python?

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to return True if the first letters are same for any 2 words sentence.  Is this a good approach:

Output expected: animal_crackers('Levelheaded Llama') --> True
animal_crackers('Crazy Kangaroo') --> False

```
def animal_crackers(text):
    words = text.split()
    if words[0][0] == words[1][0]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Ẁhat is  your problem ? The code is working as it should !

Comment: Wait, you asked "is this a good approach"...

Comment: This is probably "primarily opinion-based" on SO, but you can ask on [codereview.se] (read there help center before asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good way, but you should assign the two words to a variable each, and remove the else line, for better readability.

```py
def animal_crackers(text):
    word1, word2 = text.split()
    if word1[0] == word2[0]:
        return True
    return False
```

But, as @kobuz pointed out, your whole function can be reduced to two lines!

```py
def animal_crackers(text):
    word1, word2 = text.split()
    return word1[0] == word2[0]
```

Comment: Or just `return word1[0] == word2[0]`.